# Using a generic way to evaluate global document options

Tags: class-options

I am looking for a way to easily define and evaluate additional global document options.

Right now I am using

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
```

as the first line of my documents, I'd like to add more variables, for instance `board` or `management` and later use switches like `\ifoption{management}{then text}{else text}`

I have found the `ifdraft` package by Heiko Oberdiek which implements the desired behavior for `draft` and `final` options and was able to adjust if for the variable `state`:

```
\documentclass[state]{article}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@state
\newif\if@option@state
\DeclareOption{state}{%
\@statetrue
\@option@statetrue
}
\ProcessOptions*\relax

\newcommand*{\ifstate}{%
\if@state
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ifstate{State was set}{State was not set}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to generalize this? For example by simply defining a command `\newglobal{state}` and encapsulating the rest in a package?

Comment: `\ProcessOptions` should belong in a class or package, not in a document.

Comment: Why not create one extra (local) style file that processes these options via the standard mechanisms?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, the goal is to have a package that handles the definition, unfortunately it's far beyond my TeX knowledge.

Comment: All global options are passed to the loaded packages.

Comment: If you are only interested in boolean flags `\newif` is pretty flexible...